# What is the preferred way of calling REST services in MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios

Should I use traditional .NET methods or the MonoTouch .NET wrapper (1-1 mapping)?
Rephrase: Should I use .NET´s e.g WebClient object or NSURLRequest (in .NET)?

I can think of many situations where you have to choose between .NET and .NETified objective-c.

Is there a rule of thumb here? Because I don´t think it´s obvious.

BR

Answer (score 4):

You should probably also have a look at [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I can't really offer a fully balanced answer, however you may be interested to know that we've been using .NETs methods from an iphone to great success.

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience.